# Drive mappings being lost overnight

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting, network-share, logon-scripts

I have an interesting problem. I have a Server 2003 environment, with a Windows XP computer that continually loses its drive mappings overnight. No other users report this problem.

The user reports that drive mappings simply disappear with no real explanation. I've had the user log out and in to trigger the login script, but it does not appear to have an affect. Interestingly enough, copying the login script to the user's desktop and having them click it when mappings disappear **does** let them get their network shares back.

I'm fairly stymied. I did verify with the user that they were not simply locking the computer & walking away; but even if they were, that would only explain why the login script wasn't firing, not why the drive mappings are just dropping.

It's a desktop computer, so it isn't being taken out of the building or anything of that nature.

Comment: Are there any scheduled tasks that are running on that machine overnight? Is there anything in the event logs around that time that they disappear?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a 15 min. session timeout that is placed on all network drives where the drive will be marked as inactive. This might be what happens for computers that are not logged out. This KB article might help with that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297684

Also make sure that you are using the persistent flag properly, assuming you are using `net use` in the login script. If you are going to have to login script trigger the mapping make sure you don't use the persistent flag.

`net use` help: http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html